# Error redirecting after login

Tags: python, django, django-views

I am trying to redirect users to a create-profile form after signup.Since I don't know how to use dynamic url for LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL.I tried this little trick of linking it to a static view then finally to a dynamic view using `redirect`.It gives the error `Reverse for 'add_profile' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'username': u'badguy'}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []` (with 'badguy' truly the username of the just signed-up user').From the error,it is clearly passing the username to the view.My codes are:

```
settings.py
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/prof-change/gdyu734648dgey83y37gyyeyu8g/'

urls.py
 url(r'^prof-change/gdyu734648dgey83y37gyyeyu8g/',views.login_redir,name='login_redir'),
 url(r'^create-profile/(?P<username>\w+)/$',views.add_profile,name='create-profile'),

views.py
def login_redir(request):
    user=get_object_or_404(User,username=request.user.username)
    username=user.username
    return redirect('add_profile',username=username)

def add_profile(request,username):
    userman=User.objects.get(username=username)
    ........
    ........
```

Comment: I have added it under urls.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you reverse urls (including when you use a url name with the `redirect` shortcut), you should use the name of the *url pattern*,  not the view. The url pattern has `name='create-profile'`, so use that.

```
redirect('create-profile', username=username)
```

Comment: And that's the reason why.I made the mistake because i am always using my view-name as url-name,so i thought the former was what been used.

Comment: If I'm only using a view once, then I like to use the same name for the URL pattern. I find it less confusing and it avoids problems like this.